# Modern treatments of spectral estimation

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I need to perform and understand parameter estimation on spectra of short random time series.

Kay's "Modern Spectral Estimation: Theory and Application" treats this topic for complex-valued signals.
The book is going on 40 years old. This would be fine, except the preface mentions the techniques in its second half were still being developed at time of writing.

Is there a more contemporary treatment, or is the topic so resolved that people stopped writing books on it?

Comment: 1) a text by  percival and walden and 2) a text by langton and levin are two fairly new books that might be worth checking out. As far as older ones, priestley is a classic and jenkins and watts also. I'm not saying that you should buy these but maybe read reviews ( not necessarily amazon reviews but rather a published review ) and see if they sound more useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some more recent references covering similar topics to Kay's book:

1. *Spectral Analysis for Univariate Time Series* by Don Percival and Andrew Walden (2020)
2. *Time Series with Mixed Spectra* by Ta-Hsin Li (2014)
3. *Digital Spectral Analysis* by S. Lawrence Marple Jr. (2 ed. 2019). Kay referred to the first edition as a 'complementary text'.
4. *Digital Signal Processing and Spectral Analysis for Scientists* by Silvia Maria Alessio (2016)